How much does having an author’s website impact the chance of a short story being accepted for publication by online magazines?
It’s fairly standard advice for aspiring authors to set up a website before attempting to publish a book, as is submitting and hopefully publishing short stories with paying markets. However, I haven’t found much information on how those two steps connect. Even advice for unpublished authors often encourages including a page on the website listing published short stories. Some also suggest describing unpublished projects in process or posting a few sample short stories directly to the website. I’d like to hold off on that last option until I’ve got a few stories that I’m fairly certain are professional-level quality even if they aren’t currently marketable in active journals/magazines.
I’ve been submitting several short stories to online publications as part of my platform-building efforts, but so far none have been accepted. I know it’s typical for this to be a slow process with many rejections, but I’m wondering if having a website would improve my chances at all. I’m also in the process of building a site, so I could switch my focus to finalizing it over revising and submitting stories. But would that be worth it? Essentially, I’m wondering if there’s any advantage to prioritizing either the website or story submissions over the other, or if it’s better to keep working on both without worrying about which is finished first.

I have edited your questions tags. I think the Q&A under Marketing and Social Media are closer to what you're looking for.

It won't have much impact, unless

you are good looking and have a photo of yourself on your website, because being attractive will help sell your books;

it shows off your ability to present yourself professionally on the internet, because being a good self-marketer will help sell your books.


Otherwise, editors and agents will be most swayed by the quality of your writing and the volume of your social media following, if you have any, because having followers on social media will help sell your book.
It is unnecessary, and could be even counterproductive, to publish unpublished writing on your website. If you haven't managed to get it published, it is probably not good enough and reading it might make editors and agents think that you aren't a good writer. And if you still intend to get it published, publishing it on your website will make it unpublishable by any publisher that only accepts previously unpublished works (and that's most publishers).
The common recommendation to unpublished writers is to keep their website short. Create a home page that briefly describes what genres you work in. And with "briefly" I mean a sentence or two. Add an about page with a short biography of 200 to 300 words and a contact page with contact information and social media links (if you have significant following or great content, otherwise don't).
Your focus when creating your website should be on learning the necessary skills and tools to run and maintain a website and how to present yourself (and later your work) publicly in a pleasant and attractive manner. So try and make your website pleasing both visually and technically. It won't have much impact on selling your work to agents and editors, but you will need that skill later to help sell your books to your readers.
As an aspiriting writer of non-fiction, you need to be an established expert in your field and have a strong online presence including significant following on social media and a website that draws a lot of traffic. But as a writer of fiction, most of your time and energy should go into getting better as a writer, because ultimately it is the quality of your writing that will sell it. If you're not a naturally talented social media marketer or blogger, don't waste your time with it. Focus on writing and submitting your fiction.

Would editors in paying-market genre magazines (i.e Apex, Clarkesworld, Beneath Ceaseless Skies, etc) also prefer authors with a social media following? I know it's useful for book sales, but for a magazine/journal that already has its own platform, it seems like the individual author's following might not add as much.

@Yeslek71 Prefer, yes, because an author who can post on their social media to thousands of followers that those followers should go and buy the current issue of the magazine in which they have been published will rise sales for that magazine and gain it a few new subscribers. But I think that will only have a minor influence on their decision to publish a story or not.
